# How to set initial Firefox size (or resize) when running without win manager (headless, Xepher X over ssh)

Tags: linux, firefox, xorg, ssh-tunnel, xephyr

I'm running Firefox in Ubuntu18.04 server, on an LXC container.

On the host I'm running Xepher, which renders the X transferred over ssh.

```
Xephyr -ac -screen 1920x1200 -br -reset -terminate  :2 &
DISPLAY=:2 ssh -Y user@remote firefox &
```

It works except that Firefox only takes up about 2/3 of the screen in both width and height.  If I make scree size `1280x800` then Firefox appears smaller but still takes about 2/3 of the screen in both width and height.

I can't see anything in the [Firefox CLI startup parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options), nor does it seem to be a common use case.

**How can I set the size (without a window manager) ?**

---

Following comment suggestion I tried `xdotool`, and it succeeded ::

```
$ DISPLAY=:10 xdotool getdisplaygeometry
1920 1200
$ DISPLAY=:10 xdotool selectwindow
2097155
$ DISPLAY=:10 xdotool getwindowgeometry 2097155
Window 2097155
  Position: 0,0 (screen: 0)
  Geometry: 1280x1040
$ DISPLAY=:10 xdotool windowsize 2097155 1920 1200
```

---

Following another comment suggestion, in a single command:

```
DISPLAY=:10 xdotool search --onlyvisible --class Firefox windowsize 95% 95%
```

Comment: @dsstorefile1 - It worked.  Make it an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Note, you should be able to simplify that to a single non-interactive command: `xdotool search --onlyvisible --class Firefox windowsize 100% 100%`

Comment: @meuh - That `xdotool search --onlyvisible --class Firefox windowsize 100% 100%` works well.